# Espresso test fails with java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.abc.events.databinding.SponsorDetailBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I get this error when my espresso test runs with android databinding on the fragment layout. I dont see any crash when I use the app. Is there anyway I can avoid this?

onCreateView method in fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    SponsorDetailBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,     R.layout.fragment_sponsordetail, container, false);

    return mBinding.getRoot();
}
```

fragment_sponsordetail layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data class="SponsorDetailBinding"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topics"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sponsor_detail_topics_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/SponsorDetailText.Headers"
        android:text="@string/topics_header"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The stack trace is

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.abc.events.databinding.SponsorDetailBinding
>   at com.abc.events.ui.detail.SponsorDetailFragment.onCreateView(SponsorDetailFragment.java:102)
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
>   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:838)
>   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
>   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
>   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>   at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:280)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>   ... 24 more

Comment: Looks like the error is in your fragment. It appears to be casting a string to the binding. Normally the binding is stored as a tag. Is it possible that your fragment is trying to access the binding class as from the tag directly?

Comment: I dont see I do that anywhere.. Btw, saw your Databinding demo at developer summit yesterday. It was awesome :)

Comment: Thanks! This could be a problem with DataBindingMapper being generated in the test module. Try explicitly excluding android.databinding.DataBindingMapper.class from your package in the test module.